# Text position off in Jest test running in Jenkins

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jestjs

I'm using Jest and Puppeteer to write some DOM-related tests. The tests are passing successfully on both my local machine and a co-worker's. But I get a few failing tests when running them in Jenkins. The failing ones are all similar in terms of how they're set up, so I've pasted a simplified version of one of them below. I basically have a group element (called container) with a text element rendered inside. I expect the x-positions of `container` and its parent SVG to be the same, but instead `container` is further to the left by 1 unit. This is due to the text inside of `container` being off by 1. When this test runs in Jenkins, the `console.log` messages in the test prints:

```
container x: 7 svg x: 8 text x: 7
```

But I was expecting the output to be:

```
container x: 8 svg x: 8 text x: 8
```

which is also what I get on my local machine.

I'm wondering if anyone has an idea of what might be going on. Why would running the tests in Jenkins cause the text node to be positioned further to the left than its parent container?

The html setup for my test...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test Page</title>

  <!-- set root font size -->
  <style>
    html {
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    body {
      font-size: 0.875rem;
    }
  </style>
  
  <script type="module">
    const svgSideLength = 800
    window.testUtil = { svgSideLength }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My test...

```
  test('dummy test', async () => {
    const result = await page.evaluate(async function () {
      // svgSideLength equals 800
      const { svgSideLength } = testUtil
      document.body.innerHTML = `
      <svg height=${svgSideLength} width=${svgSideLength}>
        <g transform='translate(0, 5)'>
          <text>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</text>
        </g>
      </svg>`
      
      const containerBoundingRect = document.querySelector('g').getBoundingClientRect()
      const svgBoundingRect = document.querySelector('svg').getBoundingClientRect()
      const textBoundingRect = document.querySelector('text').getBoundingClientRect()

      console.log('container x: ', containerBoundingRect.x,
        'svg x: ', svgBoundingRect.x, 'text x: ', textBoundingRect.x)

      return containerBoundingRect.x === svgBoundingRect.x
    })

    expect(result).toBe(true)
  })
```

Some dependency versions FYI:
Puppeteer 16.2.0
Jest 29.7.0